Can Notepad++ be made to respect virtual desktops?
Notepad++ is my preferred text editor for all types of plain text work, but it has a problem that is interfering with my ability to use it at all.
I often need to use Windows 11's virtual desktop feature to separate windows for different tasks. Notepad++ is incompatible with this. Consider the following scenario:

I am working on Task A on Desktop 1. I have several windows open, including one for Notepad++.

I start working on Task B on Desktop 2. At some point I need to edit a text file. I open Notepad++, or just open a file for which Notepad++ is the default application.


Notepad++ should open a new window on Desktop 2 and open the file in it. Instead it opens the file in the window that's already open on Desktop 1 and switches my screen back to Desktop 1. Now the file is open on a different desktop from the rest of the windows for the task. Furthermore, I'm dumped into a completely different environment that I didn't ask for. If Desktop 1 and Desktop 2 are both cluttered, I may not even notice what has happened; one cluttered desktop looks a lot like another. I only notice when I need to select one of the other windows I'm working with and discover that it's not where I left it... in fact, it's not anywhere on the desktop... not anywhere on this desktop.
Is there a way around this? I'm aware of ways to open a file in a new Notepad++ window, but they are done from the original window. That doesn't help, since the original window is not on the desktop where I'm now working.

Have you selected multi-instance mode?

I had not, because the lack of automatic backup for instances after the first made it a non-starter. Nevertheless, I tried it. Notepad++ behaved exactly the same way when it was selected as when single-instance was selected. I reopened the settings dialog to be sure multi-instance mode was in fact selected -- it was -- so I must conclude that instead of creating a risk of data loss, it doesn't work at all.
